# `template <auto>` and partial class template specialization ordering

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, partial-specialization, c++17

Consider:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct Tag {};

template <typename T>
auto tag = Tag<T>{};


template <typename...>
struct SelectorImpl;

// 1
template <auto... xs>
struct SelectorImpl<std::integral_constant<decltype(xs), xs>...>
{};

// 2
template <typename T, Tag<T>* tag, auto... xs>
struct SelectorImpl<std::integral_constant<decltype(tag), tag>,
                    std::integral_constant<decltype(xs), xs>...>
{};


template <auto... params>
struct Selector
: SelectorImpl<std::integral_constant<decltype(params), params>...>
{};


int main() {
    Selector<&tag<int>, 1, 2>{};
}
```

Both gcc and clang fail to compile this, reporting that specializations of `SelectorImpl` are ambiguous. I believe that specialization #2 is more specialized. Am I wrong? Is it the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416993/class-template-specialization-partial-ordering-and-function-synthesis)? Is it a bug?

Comment: `decltype(tag)` that looks suspicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I wanted to be sure that `<char X>` has precedence over `<auto X>`. So I wrote this simple test: https://godbolt.org/g/Hy6NVB

```
template<auto...>
struct TestSingleImpl;

// 1
template<auto x>
struct TestSingleImpl<x> { static constexpr bool value = false; };

// 2
template<char x>
struct TestSingleImpl<x> { static constexpr bool value = true; };

static_assert(TestSingleImpl<1234>::value == false, "1");
static_assert(TestSingleImpl<'a'>::value == true, "2");
```

Result: yep, it has precedence (no ambiguity)

Then I applied the same example with variadic args: https://godbolt.org/g/7mWaeH

```
template <typename...>
struct Test;

// 1
template<auto v, auto... x>
struct Test<std::integral_constant<decltype(v), v>,
            std::integral_constant<decltype(x), x>...>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

// 2
template<char v, auto... x>
struct Test<std::integral_constant<char, v>,
            std::integral_constant<decltype(x), x>...>
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <auto... params>
struct Selector : Test<std::integral_constant<decltype(params), params>...> {};

static_assert(Selector<1234, 1, 2>::value == true, "1"); // 1 - ok
static_assert(Selector<'a', 1, 2>::value == false, "2"); // 2 - AMBIGUITY
```

Looks like `template<char v, auto... x>` doesn't have precedence over `template<auto... x>`.

## this looks like a HUGE bug in both CLANG and GCC

If we remove the `std::integral_constant`, it works properly: https://godbolt.org/g/grRC8h

This confirms the bug :)

```
template <auto...>
struct Test;

// 1
template<auto v, auto... x>
struct Test<v, x...>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

// 2
template<char v, auto... x>
struct Test<v, x...>
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

static_assert(Test<1234, 1, 2>::value == true, "1"); // 1 - ok
static_assert(Test<'a', 1, 2>::value == false, "2"); // 2 - ok
```

Comment: Did this get reported as a bug to the gcc/clang developers?

Comment: No idea, I don't recall reporting it