# GCC/CLang disagree on partial specialization of template template parameter

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, clang++, template-specialization

GCC and clang disagree about this code.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, template <typename...> typename Tpl> 
struct storage {
    using type_t = T;

    template <typename... Args>
    using storage_tpl = Tpl<Args...>;
};

template <typename T, template <typename...> typename>
struct F{
    constexpr static int x = 1;
};

template <typename T >
struct F<T, std::void_t>{
    constexpr static int x = 2;
};

int f() {
    using S = storage<int, std::void_t>;

    static_assert(F<int, S::storage_tpl>().x == 2);

    return F<int, S::storage_tpl>().x;
}
```

According to clang `S::storage_tpl` is not `std::void_t`; of consequence it selects the primary template F instead of the partial specialization and thus the assert.

At first glance, it looks like GCC is right because it understands that the nested template is just an alias for `std::void_t` but maybe it is too smart and the standard requires that `S::storage_tpl` and `std::void_t` must be two different templates.

Who is right?

Comment: It is not proper reference for such case, but wording used in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias "An alias template is a template which, when specialized, is equivalent to the result of substituting the template arguments of the alias template for the template parameters in the type-id" would mean that `storage_tpl` is independent template which happens to behave the same as `std::void_t`

Comment: Interesting. If you want simplify a little, you can remove the `typename T` argument from `storage` (removing also `type_t`, obviously) and from `F`. The disagreement between g++ and clang++ remain.

Comment: In [temp.class.spec.match]/2 it is said *if the template arguments of the partial specialization can be [deduced](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct) from the actual template argument list*, where deduced is a link to [temp.deduct] where... there is nothing about deduction of template argument from a template parameter (which makes sense because [temp.deduct] part is under *function template specialization*. I think the standard is underspecified. More over there is a part in the standard called *Type Equivalence* under *Template* but there is no specification for *Template Equivalence*.

Comment: alias template in combination with template template parameter is non-deduced context, basically you end up with the same problem (partial ordering and non-deduced context) as in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462410/sfinae-template-specialization-precedence.

Comment: @Oliv: Nothing prevents deducing a template template-parameter from a function argument, or even from [such a template argument used to form a function argument’s type](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#21).  But neither are we trying to deduce one: the issue here is checking for a match, and that’s not specified for non-types.

Comment: https://wg21.link/CWG1286

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is unspecified at the moment and [h/t to T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725022/gcc-clang-disagree-on-partial-specialization-of-template-template-parameter#comment92394222_52725022) it looks like this is covered by [CWG defect report 1286](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286) which says:

> Issue 1244 was resolved by changing the example in 17.5 [temp.type]
>   paragraph 1 from
>
> ```
>  template<template<class> class TT> struct X { };
>   template<class> struct Y { };
>   template<class T> using Z = Y<T>;
>   X<Y> y;
>   X<Z> z;
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
>   template<class T> struct X { };
>   template<class> struct Y { };
>   template<class T> using Z = Y<T>;
>   X<Y<int> > y;
>   X<Z<int> > z;
> ```
>
> In fact, the original intent was that the example should have been
>   correct as written; however, the normative wording to make it so was
>   missing. The current wording of 17.6.7 [temp.alias] deals only with
>   the equivalence of a specialization of an alias template with the
>   type-id after substitution. Wording needs to be added specifying under
>   what circumstances an alias template itself is equivalent to a class
>   template.

and proposed the following resolution:

> Add the following as a new paragraph following 17.6.7 [temp.alias]
>   paragraph 2:
>
> When the type-id in the declaration of alias template (call it A) consists of a simple-template-id in which the template-argument-list
>   consists of a list of identifiers naming each template-parameter of A
>   exactly once in the same order in which they appear in A's
>   template-parameter-list, the alias template is equivalent to the
>   template named in the simple-template-id (call it T) if A and T have
>   the same number of template-parameters. [Footnote: **This rule is
>   transitive: if an alias template A is equivalent to another alias
>   template B that is equivalent to a class template C, then A is also
>   equivalent to C, and A and B are also equivalent to each other**. —end
>   footnote] [Example:
>
> ```
>   template<typename T, U = T> struct A;
>
>   template<typename V, typename W>
>     using B = A<V, W>;                // equivalent to A
>
>   template<typename V, typename W>
>     using C = A<V>;                   // not equivalent to A:
>                                       // not all parameters used
>
>   template<typename V>
>     using D = A<V>;                   // not equivalent to A:
>                                       // different number of parameters
>
>   template<typename V, typename W>
>     using E = A<W, V>;                // not equivalent to A:
>                                       // template-arguments in wrong order
>
>   template<typename V, typename W = int>
>     using F = A<V, W>;                // equivalent to A:
>                                       // default arguments not considered
>
>   template<typename V, typename W>
>     using G = A<V, W>;                // equivalent to A and B
>
>   template<typename V, typename W>
>     using H = E<V, W>;                // equivalent to E
>
>   template<typename V, typename W>
>     using I = A<V, typename W::type>; // not equivalent to A:
>                                       // argument not identifier
> ```
>
> > —end example]

but there are issues with this resolution and the defect report is still active.