# c++ template specialization with std::enable_if not working

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I've a simple primary function template that I want to partially specialize.

```
template< typename T >
void SetAttribute( const T& value )
{
  static_assert( false, "SetAttribute: wrong type!" );
}

template<> void SetAttribute( const bool& value ) {}

template<> void SetAttribute( const std::wstring& value ) {}

template< typename T >
void SetAttribute( const typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral< T >::value >::type& value ) {}

int main()
{
  SetAttribute( std::wstring( L"bla" ) );
  SetAttribute( bool( true ) );
  SetAttribute( std::uint32_t( 1 ) ); // error C2338: SetAttribute: wrong type!

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with VS 2015 Update 3, then I'll get an error on the 3d call (see comment). why? I don't understand why the 3d specialization is not used.

Thx
Fred

Comment: i don't have an explanation on why this is not working, need to check c++ standard for that, but there are other ways to write this if you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial ordering with function template having undeduced context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180325/partial-ordering-with-function-template-having-undeduced-context)

Comment: 2 reason, it's non-deduced context, even if it can deduced, the type is always void

Comment: @Raxvan: well, could you please tell me the other ways?

Comment: @Danh: well, then none of the call should work. The 'wstring' and 'bool' ones are compiling !

Comment: in `std::enable_if< std::is_integral< T >::value >::type` T cannot be deduced.

Comment: @all: well ok! But how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I believe none of those call should work, since `static_assert( false, "SetAttribute: wrong type!" );` doesn't depend on template params

Comment: @Fred use two structs for `invalid` and `integrals` with static functions for implementations, then use `std::conditional` in `SetAttribute` to choose which one you want. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `T` in a [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts)

```
template< typename T >
void SetAttribute( const typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral< T >::value >::type& value ) {}
                                                                    ^
```

Functions are probably the wrong tool for this job (they cannot be partially specialized), a possible workaround if you insist in using functions could be a combination of tag dispatching and specializations

```
template<class T>
void SetAttribute(const T&, std::true_type) {}

template<class T>
void SetAttribute(const T& value, std::false_type)
{
  static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "SetAttribute: wrong type!");
}

template< typename T >
void SetAttribute(const T& value)
{
  SetAttribute(value, std::is_integral<T>());
}

template<> void SetAttribute(const bool&) {}

template<> void SetAttribute(const std::wstring&) {}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e115faa5ecc433b9)</kbd>

Quite unreadable if you ask me..

Comment: Alternatively you could use enable_if on the return type or on a template parameter default argument.

Comment: @ymett: I've tried it, but doesn't work either... or perhaps, I did it wrong?

Comment: @Fred What exactly did you do and what exactly happened?